# How to implement an MCI parser in java

Tags: java, c++

I want to parse an mci file format for storing petri net unfolding prefixes in java so that I can use it to generate SAT formula

the below text describes the MCI file format for storing
Petri net unfolding prefixes.

Below, CHAR is a 1-byte char, and UINT4 is a little-endian
(i.e. the least significant byte is at the lowest address,
and the other bytes follow in increasing order of
significance.) 4-byte unsigned int (Intel is little-endian).

- the total number of conditions (UINT4)
- the total number of events (UINT4)
- for each event (from first to last):
  -- the number of the original transition (UINT4)
- for each condition (from first to last):
  --  the number of the original place (UINT4)
  --  the number of the preset event (UINT4); 
      it's 0 if the condition is initial
  --  NULL(UINT4)-terminated list of postset events numbers (UINT4)
- for each cut-off event
  --  the number of cut-off event (UINT4)
  --  the number of corresponding event (UINT4) or 
      NULL(UINT4) if the corresponding event is the 
      virtual initial event
- separating NULL(UINT4)
- for each configuration:
  -- NULL(UINT4)-terminated list of events numbers. 
     (This is used by some ancient model checker; 
     PUNF doesn't create it and just outputs the 
     terminating NULL(UINT4).)
- separating NULL(UINT4)
- the total number of places in the original net (UINT4)
- the total number of transitions the in original net (UINT4)
- the maximal string length for place/transition names (UINT4) 
  (useful for memory allocation in the parser)
- for each place in original net:
  -- the name (NULL(CHAR)-terminated string)
- separating NULL(UINT4)
- for each transition in original net:
  -- the name (NULL(CHAR)-terminated string)
- terminating NULL(UINT4).

***Note : I have got the implementation in C++ but I want it in java. For your info. I have used so many tools to convert it to java but none of them worked completely. So, I will appreciate any help from you guys.More, I ll put the code in C++ if needed.***

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html).

This should allow you to read your individual uint4 and characters.